# Как правильно добавить в приложение consent form?

Tags: android, kotlin, gdpr

Мне в приложение надо добавить **consent** в связи с чем возникли следующие вопросы:

1. После **SplashScreen** у меня включается **Interstitial ads**, если я хочу добавить consent form,
   я так понимаю, мне надо добавить его до появления первой рекламы. Это нормально показывать его сразу на **SplashScreen**? И в `onConsentFormClosed()` показывать **Interstitial ads**, а после закрытия рекламы как и раньше просто делать переход на **MainActivity**?
2. В моем приложении много окон с разной рекламой(**Banner, Interstitial, Native**).

После выбора на **Consent form**:

[image: consent form]

ответ уходит в адмоб и дальше он сам поймет какую рекламу отдавать?
Или нужно проверять каждый раз перед показом рекламы, что выбрал пользователь, и показывать другую рекламу в ручную т.е. если у меня был такой код для показа **banner_ads**:

```
val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
adView!!.loadAd(adRequest)
```

Мне после добавления **consent** надо что-то добавлять или выполнять какие-то проверки?

3. В приложении есть подписка, если пользователь выбирает вариант: **Pay for the ad-free version**, его можно просто перебросить на экран подписки, или лучше сразу там же вызывать google-ский диалог с оплатой подписки: [image: google subscribe dialog]?
4. Я так понял из вот этого урока: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jJuhnFiHAb0, по умолчанию идет `ConsentStatus.PERSONALIZED`, если `ConsentStatus.NON_PERSONALIZED` т.е. выбран вариант **No, see ads that are less relevant**, достаточно просто добавить вот эти строки из документации:

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("npa", "1");

AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extras)
        .build();
```

Так ли это?

5. Обязательно ли создавать свой **privacy policy**? Для вот этой части:

```
URL privacyUrl = null;
try {
    // TODO: Replace with your app's privacy policy URL.
    privacyUrl = new URL("https://www.your.com/privacyurl");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    // Handle error.
}
```

6. На сколько это вообще критично(делаю часть которая для Европы), я так понимаю приложения особо не банят, но могут?!

Подскажите пожалуйста, по выше перечисленным вопросам, и если есть советы по внедрению **consent form** их тоже хотелось бы услышать.